# Is there a way to retrieve data from a php array?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get managers to fill out a form using a plugin in WordPress, but the data keeps returning "-" instead of the actual data from an array.

I've tried modifying the pages that relate to the performance reviews as well as looked at the functions.php file.

This is the code that I assume keeps giving me the "-".

```
<?php echo isset( $performance_trainingstage[ $row-> trainingstage ] ) ? $performance_trainingstage[ $row-> trainingstage ] : '-'; ?>
```

This is the code that I assume the above code is supposed to be pulling from:

```
<?php erp_html_form_input( array(
        'label'   => __( 'Training Stage', 'erp' ),
        'name'    => 'trainingstage',
        'value'   => '',
        'class'   => 'erp-hrm-select2',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'id'      => 'performance_trainingstage',
        'options' => array("FOH 1", "FOH 2", "FOH 3", "BOH 1", "BOH 2", "BOH 3", "Prep", "Champion of Excellence", "Team Trainer", 'erp') + erp_performance_rating()
    ) ); ?>
```

I would like the results to give me whatever option it is I selected: FOH 1, FOH 2, etc.

Comment: What are the results of print_r($performance_trainingstage)?

Comment: `$row-> trainingstage` there seems to be a space in here. If that's in your actual code it'll be causing you problems.

Comment: @symlink I tried changing to print_r($performance_trainingstage) and it didn't input any of the fields.

Comment: @CalumHalpin that space was put in there when the code went to a new line. I verified and there isn't a space.